# SQL Server, trying to add constraint while creating table, wherein there is a field 'ssn_nr' for ssn's

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table with a column `ssn_nr`. I have inserted ssn's with 9 digits. However, there are ssn's starting from '0' have removed itself, which resultant few ssn's showing with only 8 digits.

Example: I tried to insert ssn's like: 089562715,985624851...(having 9 digits), data type was used 'int' not null. Execution was successful, but ssn's start's with '0' automatically got removed.

Desired result: I want all ssn's should be in 9 digits, no matter if any ssn start's with having single or multiple '0' (exm for ssn: 002154698, 025489635, 000548965).

Comment: Use a `varchar()` to store the social security numbers, rather than a numeric type.

Comment: You should store them encrypted since this is sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

Numeric Datatypes does not allow preceding zero's. So I recommend you change the data type as Varchar for this column.

```
alter table yourtable
alter column SSN varchar(10)
```

Then update the column to add preceding zero to the existing records

```
update yourtable set ssn = right('000000000'+SSN,9)
```

If altering the field is not possible, then you can try casting the column as varchar and add preceding zero's while selecting the records. Like this

```
select SSN =right('000000000'+SSN,9) from yourtable
```

But I prefer altering the column.

Comment: Numeric data types do store insignificant zeros but those are commonly suppressed by the client application. I agree varchar/char is a better choice for data like SSNs, account numbers, etc. Formatting data for display purposes in T-SQL is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert zeros in a int field, you could use varchar(9) or treat it in the select with something like:

```
RIGHT('000000000'+ISNULL(ssn_nr,''),9)
```